# Can we can have print statement in classes without any function/task in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

Can we can have print statement in classes without any function/task in SystemVerilog?

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/8Y8

```
class A;
 int x=10;
 $display("x=%d",x);
 endclass

module abc;
 A a;
 initial begin
   a=new();
 end
endmodule
```

Comment: It would help to explain why you think you want to do this. Is it to help debug your code? There are ways of setting breakpoints and executing print statements. But in any case, you need to latch on to a particular procedural statement to specify _when_ you want the print statement to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  According to the IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 8.3 "Syntax", a class may only contain the following items:

```
class_item ::= 
{ attribute_instance } class_property
| { attribute_instance } class_method
| { attribute_instance } class_constraint
| { attribute_instance } class_declaration
| { attribute_instance } covergroup_declaration
| local_parameter_declaration ;
| parameter_declaration7 ;
| ;
```

A `$display` statement may only occur in a procedural block (initial, always, final) or a task/function body.

Typically, you need to create a display function in the class, then call it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Either you have to print in a dedicated task/function or in the class *constructor*.

LRM states that: 
A display/monitor/strobe/write statement may only occur in a procedural block or in a task/function body.

We can display the default values of variables, when object is created as follows. A better option is using display in constructor itself.

```
class A; 
int x=10; 
function void new(); // constructor
  $display("x=%d",x); 
endfunction
endclass
```

Comment: "void" not allowed for constructosr.